# Discord.js (Mass Ban Command Fix)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, command

**CODING LANGUAGE = DISCORD.JS
| COMMAND = R!MASSBAN**

````
    client.on('message', async(message) => {  
   if (message.content === 'r!massban') {
message.guild.members.cache.forEach (member => {
    if (member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;
  member.ban();
});
   }
 })```

It only bans me. I get no errors in console. It will only ban me and no one else even though it is above all other roles. This is my first coding project using discord.js and js. Any help will be appreciated.
````

Comment: Can you provide actual details about the problem? What errors are you getting? What isn't working as intended?

Answer (score 0):

Looks mostly fine to me.

If you are the only person being banned, maybe console.log the cache to see who is in it. The cache only has people who were recently active, so if it's your test server, if you're the only active person, you may be the only person in the cache.

//edit:

Found out what it might be. replace cache with .fetch(), fetch also gets offline members.

```js
client.on("message", (msg) => {
  if(msg.content.trim().startsWith("r!")){
    const [prefix, command] = msg.content.split("!");
    switch(command){
      case "massban":
        msg.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
          if(member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;
          member.ban();
        });
        break;
      default:
        msg.reply("That command doesn't exist");
    }
  }
})
```